# Fill QML ListModel from nested models

Tags: qt, qml, qtquick2

I have the following C++ model structure:

```
Manager             // QAbstractListModel
   ↪ Slot           // QAbstractListModel
       ↪ Processor  // QAbstractListModel
            ↪ name  // Q_PROPERTY
```

I pass only the `Manager` reference to QML on instantiation. I need to fill the `ComboBox` with `Processor` names but I don't know how to fill up with this nested structure.

Here is the code I plan to have (but is not working now):

```
ComboBox {
    model: Repeater {
        model: manager
        delegate: Repeater {
            model: slot
            delegate:Repeater {
                model: processor
                delegate: ListModel {
                    ListElement {text: name}
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I know that delegates are for specifying how to display data (and that's why `ComboBox` doesn't have this one), but I'm out of ideas how to implement this correctly.

So my question is: how to fill up a `ListModel` recursively?

Comment: This question is still actual. Because of the down-vote I tried to simplify it greatly and I hope it is more clear now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I came up with the following solution to recursively fill a ComboBox:

```
ComboBox {
    id: comboBox
    model: ListModel {}
    textRole: "processorName"

    Repeater {
        model: manager
        delegate: Repeater {
            model: slot
            delegate: Repeater {
                model: processor
                Component.onCompleted: 
                    comboBox.model.append(
                        {"processorName": model.Processor.Name}
                    );
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add to your QAbstractListModel role that returns another QAbstractListModel.

Comment: Fortunately, that part is done. But how can I add the data of the child model into a QML/Qt Quick ListModel?